# Write World File option blocked when exporting Layout View in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, export, jpg, world-file

When i try to export map to jpg file in ArcGIS DEsktop 10.3, the "write world file" is blocked.

How can i solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option is only available in Data View.

If you are in Layout View then you will not be able to Write a World File.

This software behaviour is unchanged in ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop Pre-release.

For it to be enhanced I suggest you submit an [ArcGIS Idea](http://arcgis.ideas.com).  I was surprised not to find one when I looked just now.  If you do submit one then I suggest targeting ArcGIS Pro (where this functionality appears to be the same as ArcMap's) rather than ArcMap because I think it will have a better chance of being implemented there.

Answer (score 1):

*I am assuming that data frame boundaries in layout view coincide with page.*

This can be done manually, because you truly need just 3 values to create world file: cell size and coordinates of upper left corner of exported image.

Export layout to raster file and note it's height in pixels, e.g. 842.
To find 3 magic numbers activate python window from layout view and type:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
ext=df.extent
```

This gives you access to data frame extent. Following 3 lines will give you numbers:

```
ext.height/842
ext.XMin
ext.YMax
```

to be placed in relevant lines inside world file.